# Matlab: for loop on vector. Weird speed behaviour?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, optimization

I was playing a bit with the for loop on matlab, I know that often it is possible to avoid them and in that case, much much faster. But if I really want to go through all the element of the vector V , I did that little test:

```
n=50000000;
V =1:n;

s1 = 0;
tic
for x=V
    s1 = s1+x;
end
toc

s2 = 0;
tic
for ind=1:numel(V)
    s2 = s2+V(ind);
end
toc
```

s1 et s2 are equal (normal) but it takes 24.63 sec for the first loop and only  0.48 sec for the second one.

I was a bit surprised by these numbers. Is it something known ? does anyone have any explanation ?

Comment: This kind of syntax is new to me "for x=V". Perhaps it is related to parsing of this line of code

Comment: This behavior is weird. (Although the first loop doesn't take that much time in my system with MATLAB 2016a). It takes 1.30~1.35 sec for me! while the second loop takes 0.60~0.65 sec )

Comment: Btw, writing `s3 = 0; for x=1:50000000, s3 = s3+x; end` is even faster! (half time of s2 version)

Comment: @User1551892 well you can always do for i=a:b:c so I thought "why not an other vector ?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama weird, I am on Matlab 2014b

Comment: @matheburg yeah sure and doing sum(V) is probably also much faster ;) it was just an example for a more general case where the vector is not necessarily 1:n and what I do in the loop is not necessarily just a sum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably caused by **memory allocation**. The statement in case 1,

> `for x=V`

has to **create a copy** of `V`. Why do we know? If you modify `V` within the loop `x` won't be affected: it will still run through the original `V` values.

On the other hand, the statement in case 2,

> `for ind=1:numel(V)`

**doesn't actually create** the vector `1:numel(V)`. From `help for`,

> Long loops are more memory efficient when the colon expression appears in the for statement since the index vector is never created.

The fact that no memory needs to be allocated probably accounts for the increase of speed, at least in part.

To test this, let's change `for ind=1:numel(V)` to `for ind=[1:numel(V)]`. This will force creation of the vector `1:numel(V)`. Then the running time should be similar to case 1, or indeed a little larger because we still need to index into `V` with `V(ind)`.

These are the running times on my computer:

```
% Case 1
n=50000000;
V =1:n;
s1 = 0;
tic
for x=V
    s1 = s1+x;
end
toc

% Case 2
s2 = 0;
tic
for ind=1:numel(V)
    s2 = s2+V(ind);
end
toc

% Case 3
s3 = 0;
tic
for ind=[1:numel(V)]
    s3 = s3+V(ind);
end
toc
```

Results:

```
Elapsed time is 0.610825 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.182983 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.831321 seconds.
```

Comment: Why doesn't increase the adding of a `W = V;` before case 2 the run time to the level of case 1?

Comment: @matheburg Probably because Matlab uses [copy-on-write](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/10/memory-management-for-functions-and-variables/), so no "real" copy is actually done at that point

Comment: @LuisMendo the example with [1:numel(V)] is very interesting, it looks like the explanation :) which matlab version are you running ? the difference in execution time are huge between yours and mine ! in my case case 1 and case 3: around 25 sec and case 2: 0.5 sec (on a brand-new macbook pro and matlab 2014b)

edit: and I did not realize that when I do "for i=V" I can modify V in the loop without affecting the loop !

Comment: @pierremomo There's probably more going on behind the scenes, but memory allocation surely is at least part of the explanation. I'm using R2016b in Windows on a fairly new computer. Perhaps the [new execution engine introduced in R2015b](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/) is the reason of the smaller running times